# Django FileResponse not working with uwsgi

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, uwsgi, gunicorn

I have the following code which takes in an arbitrary audio stream and converts it to mp3 on the fly using ffmpeg. The code works fine when run using `python manage.py runserver` but is not working when run using uwsgi server.

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def mp3(request):
    audiourl = request.session['audiourl']
    title = request.session['title']
    process = Popen('ffmpeg -i "{}" -f mp3 -'.format(audiourl), shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    response = FileResponse(process.stdout)
    fname = title + '.mp3'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition(fname)
    return response
```

It might work with gunicorn but I prefer to use uwsgi if possible. Kindly post your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your current configurations..

Comment: How about passing --enable-threads config option when you startup uwsgi server?

Comment: Nope I enabled threads not yet working.

Comment: @Sandeep did you get a solution for this. Using nginx-uwsgi

Comment: Not yet. I am using python manage.py server at the moment. But it runs in single threaded mode so can't allow multiple user connections.

Comment: Guys general question does that mean uwsgi doesn't support streaming result from any background tasks spawned from views.py?